# Juniper SSG5 suddenly slow throughput

Tags: firewall, juniper, netscreen, ssg5

I'm trying to find out where in my configuration the problem might be.  About a month ago we were easily getting 100 up 50 down through our provider through the Juniper SSG5. Starting a few weeks ago that changed.  If I plug directly into the cable modem everything is fine and I get full speed.  If I plug into the netscreen it drops down to about 20 - 25 down and 20 - 25 up.  I've replaced cables as well as the netscreen it's self.  The only thing left seems to be the configuration.

```
unset key protection enable
set clock timezone -7
set clock dst recurring start-weekday 2 0 3 02:00 end-weekday 1 0 11 02:00
set vrouter trust-vr sharable
set vrouter "untrust-vr"
exit
set vrouter "trust-vr"
unset auto-route-export
exit
set service "AV-iPhone" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 80-80 
set service "AV-iPhone" + tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 41786-41786 
set service "AV-iPhone" timeout never
set service "DVR" protocol tcp src-port 37777-37777 dst-port 37777-37777 
set service "DVR" + tcp src-port 3000-3000 dst-port 3000-3000 
set service "DVR" timeout never
set service "Crestron-Mobile" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 37777-37777 timeout never 
set service "Crestron-Processor" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 41794-41794 
set service "Crestron-Processor2" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 41795-41795 
set service "Crestron-Processor3" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 41781-41781 
set service "Crestron-Processor4" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 6000-6000 
set alg appleichat enable
unset alg appleichat re-assembly enable
set alg sctp enable
set auth-server "Local" id 0
set auth-server "Local" server-name "Local"
set auth default auth server "Local"
set auth radius accounting port 1646
set admin name "XXXXXXXXXX"
set admin password "XXXXXXXXXX"
set admin auth web timeout 10
set admin auth dial-in timeout 3
set admin auth server "Local"
set admin format dos
set zone "Trust" vrouter "trust-vr"
set zone "Untrust" vrouter "trust-vr"
set zone "DMZ" vrouter "trust-vr"
set zone "VLAN" vrouter "trust-vr"
set zone "Untrust-Tun" vrouter "trust-vr"
set zone "Trust" tcp-rst 
set zone "Trust" asymmetric-vpn
set zone "Untrust" block 
unset zone "Untrust" tcp-rst 
set zone "MGT" block 
unset zone "V1-Trust" tcp-rst 
unset zone "V1-Untrust" tcp-rst 
set zone "DMZ" tcp-rst 
unset zone "V1-DMZ" tcp-rst 
unset zone "VLAN" tcp-rst 
set zone "Untrust" screen tear-drop
set zone "Untrust" screen syn-flood
set zone "Untrust" screen ping-death
set zone "Untrust" screen ip-filter-src
set zone "Untrust" screen land
set zone "V1-Untrust" screen tear-drop
set zone "V1-Untrust" screen syn-flood
set zone "V1-Untrust" screen ping-death
set zone "V1-Untrust" screen ip-filter-src
set zone "V1-Untrust" screen land
set interface "ethernet0/0" zone "Untrust"
set interface "ethernet0/1" zone "DMZ"
set interface "bgroup0" zone "Trust"
set interface "tunnel.1" zone "Trust"
set interface "tunnel.2" zone "Trust"
set interface bgroup0 port ethernet0/2
set interface bgroup0 port ethernet0/3
set interface bgroup0 port ethernet0/4
set interface bgroup0 port ethernet0/5
set interface bgroup0 port ethernet0/6
unset interface vlan1 ip
set interface ethernet0/0 ip XXXXXXXXXX/27
set interface ethernet0/0 route
set interface bgroup0 ip XXXXXXXXXX/24
set interface bgroup0 nat
set interface tunnel.1 ip XXXXXXXXXX/30
set interface tunnel.2 ip XXXXXXXXXX/30
set interface tunnel.1 mtu 1436
set interface tunnel.2 mtu 1436
unset interface vlan1 bypass-others-ipsec
unset interface vlan1 bypass-non-ip
unset interface ethernet0/0 ip manageable
set interface bgroup0 ip manageable
set interface bgroup0 manage mtrace
set interface ethernet0/0 vip interface-ip 37777 "Crestron-Mobile" XXXXXXXXXX
set interface ethernet0/0 vip interface-ip 41794 "Crestron-Processor" XXXXXXXXXX
set interface ethernet0/0 vip interface-ip 41795 "Crestron-Processor2" XXXXXXXXXX
set interface ethernet0/0 vip interface-ip 41781 "Crestron-Processor3" XXXXXXXXXX
set interface ethernet0/0 vip interface-ip 6000 "Crestron-Processor4" XXXXXXXXXX
set interface ethernet0/0 vip interface-ip 12001 "Crestron-Processor2" XXXXXXXXXX
set interface bgroup0 dhcp server service
set interface bgroup0 dhcp server enable
set interface bgroup0 dhcp server option gateway XXXXXXXXXX
set interface bgroup0 dhcp server option dns1 XXXXXXXXXX
set interface bgroup0 dhcp server option dns2 XXXXXXXXXX
set interface bgroup0 dhcp server ip XXXXXXXXXX to XXXXXXXXXX 
unset interface bgroup0 dhcp server config next-server-ip
set interface "serial0/0" modem settings "USR" init "AT&F"
set interface "serial0/0" modem settings "USR" active
set interface "serial0/0" modem speed 115200
set interface "serial0/0" modem retry 3
set interface "serial0/0" modem interval 10
set interface "serial0/0" modem idle-time 10
set flow tcp-mss
unset flow tcp-syn-check
unset flow tcp-syn-bit-check
set flow reverse-route clear-text prefer
set flow reverse-route tunnel always
set flow vpn-tcp-mss 1387
set pki authority default scep mode "auto"
set pki x509 default cert-path partial
set address "Trust" "XXXXXXXXXX/16" XXXXXXXXXX 255.255.0.0
set address "Trust" "XXXXXXXXXX/24" XXXXXXXXXX 255.255.255.0
set address "Trust" "XXXXXXXXXX/24" XXXXXXXXXX 255.255.255.0
set address "Trust" "XXXXXXXXXX/32" XXXXXXXXXX 255.255.255.255
set address "Trust" "AV-Phone" XXXXXXXXXX 255.255.255.255 "Audio Video iPhone stuff"
set address "Trust" "DVR" XXXXXXXXXX 255.255.255.255 "DVR"
set ippool "VPN Client IPs" XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX
set user "Shared IKE User" uid 8
set user "Shared IKE User" ike-id fqdn "vpntracker.local" share-limit 1
set user "Shared IKE User" type ike
set user "Shared IKE User" "enable"
set user "XXXXXXXXXX" uid 10
set user "XXXXXXXXXX" type xauth
set user "XXXXXXXXXX" password "XXXXXXXXXX"
unset user "XXXXXXXXXX" type auth
set user "XXXXXXXXXX" "enable"
set user "XXXXXXXXXX" uid 12
set user "XXXXXXXXXX" type xauth
set user "XXXXXXXXXX" password "XXXXXXXXXX"
unset user "XXXXXXXXXX" type auth
set user "XXXXXXXXXX" "enable"
set user "XXXXXXXXXX" uid 9
set user "XXXXXXXXXX" type xauth
set user "XXXXXXXXXX" password "XXXXXXXXXX"
unset user "XXXXXXXXXX" type auth
set user "XXXXXXXXXX" "enable"
set user "XXXXXXXXXX" uid 11
set user "XXXXXXXXXX" type xauth
set user "XXXXXXXXXX" password "XXXXXXXXXX"
unset user "XXXXXXXXXX" type auth
set user "XXXXXXXXXX" "enable"
set user "XXXXXXXXXX" uid 7
set user "XXXXXXXXXX" type xauth
set user "XXXXXXXXXX" password "XXXXXXXXXX"
unset user "XXXXXXXXXX" type auth
set user "XXXXXXXXXX" "enable"
set user "XXXXXXXXXX" uid 13
set user "XXXXXXXXXX" type xauth
set user "XXXXXXXXXX" password "XXXXXXXXXX"
unset user "XXXXXXXXXX" type auth
set user "XXXXXXXXXX" "enable"
set user-group "Shared VPN Group" id 3
set user-group "Shared VPN Group" user "Shared IKE User"
set crypto-policy
exit
set ike p1-proposal "ike-prop-vpn-bb6bb6a5-1" preshare group2 esp aes128 sha-1 second 28800
set ike p1-proposal "ike-prop-vpn-bb6bb6a5-2" preshare group2 esp aes128 sha-1 second 28800
set ike p2-proposal "ipsec-prop-vpn-bb6bb6a5-1" group2 esp aes128 sha-1 second 3600
set ike p2-proposal "ipsec-prop-vpn-bb6bb6a5-2" group2 esp aes128 sha-1 second 3600
set ike gateway "gw-vpn-bb6bb6a5-1" address XXXXXXXXXX id "XXXXXXXXXX" Main outgoing-interface "ethernet0/0" preshare "XXXXXXXXXX" proposal "ike-prop-vpn-bb6bb6a5-1"
set ike gateway "gw-vpn-bb6bb6a5-1" dpd-liveness interval 10
set ike gateway "gw-vpn-bb6bb6a5-2" address XXXXXXXXXX id "XXXXXXXXXX" Main outgoing-interface "ethernet0/0" preshare "XXXXXXXXXX" proposal "ike-prop-vpn-bb6bb6a5-2"
set ike gateway "gw-vpn-bb6bb6a5-2" dpd-liveness interval 10
set ike gateway "VPN Tracker" dialup "Shared VPN Group" Aggr outgoing-interface "ethernet0/0" preshare "XXXXXXXXXX" sec-level standard
unset ike gateway "VPN Tracker" nat-traversal udp-checksum
set ike gateway "VPN Tracker" nat-traversal keepalive-frequency 5
set ike gateway "VPN Tracker" xauth
unset ike gateway "VPN Tracker" xauth do-edipi-auth
set ike respond-bad-spi 1
set ike ikev2 ike-sa-soft-lifetime 60
unset ike ikeid-enumeration
unset ike dos-protection
unset ipsec access-session enable
set ipsec access-session maximum 5000
set ipsec access-session upper-threshold 0
set ipsec access-session lower-threshold 0
set ipsec access-session dead-p2-sa-timeout 0
unset ipsec access-session log-error
unset ipsec access-session info-exch-connected
unset ipsec access-session use-error-log
set xauth default ippool "VPN Client IPs"
set vpn "IPSEC-vpn-bb6bb6a5-1" gateway "gw-vpn-bb6bb6a5-1" replay tunnel idletime 0 proposal "ipsec-prop-vpn-bb6bb6a5-1" 
set vpn "IPSEC-vpn-bb6bb6a5-1" id 0x1 bind interface tunnel.1
set vpn "IPSEC-vpn-bb6bb6a5-2" gateway "gw-vpn-bb6bb6a5-2" replay tunnel idletime 0 proposal "ipsec-prop-vpn-bb6bb6a5-2" 
set vpn "IPSEC-vpn-bb6bb6a5-2" id 0x2 bind interface tunnel.2
set vpn "VPN Tracker" gateway "VPN Tracker" no-replay tunnel idletime 0 sec-level standard
set vrouter "untrust-vr"
exit
set vrouter "trust-vr"
exit
set url protocol websense
exit
set policy id 6 from "Untrust" to "Trust"  "Dial-Up VPN" "XXXXXXXXXX/24" "ANY" tunnel vpn "VPN Tracker" id 0x6 
set policy id 6
exit
set policy id 5 from "Untrust" to "Trust"  "Any" "XXXXXXXXXX/24" "ANY" permit 
set policy id 5
exit
set policy id 1 from "Trust" to "Untrust"  "Any" "Any" "ANY" permit traffic priority 0 mbw 100000
set policy id 1
exit
set policy id 2 name "AV-iPhone" from "Untrust" to "Trust"  "Any" "AV-Phone" "AV-iPhone" permit 
set policy id 2
exit
set policy id 4 name "Crestron-Mobile" from "Untrust" to "Trust"  "Any" "VIP(ethernet0/0)" "Crestron-Mobile" permit 
set policy id 4
exit
set policy id 7 from "Untrust" to "Trust"  "Dial-Up VPN" "XXXXXXXXXX/16" "ANY" tunnel vpn "VPN Tracker" id 0x7 
set policy id 7
exit
set policy id 8 name "Crestron-Processor" from "Untrust" to "Trust"  "Any" "VIP(ethernet0/0)" "Crestron-Processor" permit 
set policy id 8
exit
set policy id 9 name "Crestron-Mobile" from "Untrust" to "Trust"  "Any" "VIP(ethernet0/0)" "Crestron-Processor2" permit 
set policy id 9
exit
set policy id 10 name "Crestron-Mobile" from "Untrust" to "Trust"  "Any" "VIP(ethernet0/0)" "Crestron-Processor3" permit 
set policy id 10
exit
set policy id 11 name "Crestron-Mobile" from "Untrust" to "Trust"  "Any" "VIP(ethernet0/0)" "Crestron-Processor4" permit 
set policy id 11
exit
set nsmgmt bulkcli reboot-timeout 60
set ssh version v2
set ssh enable
set config lock timeout 5
unset license-key auto-update
set telnet client enable
set snmp port listen 161
set snmp port trap 162
set vrouter "untrust-vr"
exit
set vrouter "trust-vr"
set max-ecmp-routes 2
set protocol bgp 65000
set enable
set hold-time 30
set neighbor 169.254.249.25 remote-as 7224
set neighbor 169.254.249.25 enable
set neighbor 169.254.249.29 remote-as 7224
set neighbor 169.254.249.29 enable
set ipv4 advertise-def-route
set ipv4 neighbor 169.254.249.25 activate
set ipv4 neighbor 169.254.249.29 activate
set ipv4 network 0.0.0.0/0

exit
unset add-default-route
set route XXXXXXXXXX/0 interface ethernet0/0
exit
set interface tunnel.1 protocol bgp
set interface tunnel.2 protocol bgp
set vrouter "untrust-vr"
exit
set vrouter "trust-vr"
exit
```

Does anyone see anything obvious?

Comment: Any news for your issue ? Did you maked the test

Comment: Two things, one I don't have a small SOHO router available - and two it really doesn't solve the issue. I have all of the packet inspection off and if one day the router is capable of doing 50 up/down the next day it shouldn't suddenly drop to 20/20. There's got to be a larger problem than just the device.  I've used this exact model before in larger installations and had it doing much higher speeds.

Comment: It's your router then, try a firmware upgrade. As your test with your computer ruled out that the link is ok.

Comment: It's on the latest firmware AND I replaced the router at the end of last week with a new one thinking it was a hardware issue. The consistent thing is the configuration.

Comment: I agree, but your config is really simple, nothing much. Try setting the wan int at 100mb full, maybe a negotiation error with the modem. (set interface eth0/1 phy full 100mb)

Comment: Agreed, very simple config that's why I'm frustrated.  I've tested at 100mb full and get the same results.  I just tried it again, same deal.

Answer (score 0):

Try a small SOHO router (like a dlink or linksys). The SSG5 is an entry level firewall, on a big ISP link the packet inspection service can kill the firewal, while a SOHO router inspect nothing, like your PC too.

If the test is ok, you will need to upgrade the router.

Comment: There's no excuse for the current throughput, though. Speeds of 20 up/down with no one else but me testing the circuit.  I'm aware that it's entry level, there are also only 7 people in this office.

Comment: @DaveHolland A 100mbps line kill a Cisco ASA5505, got a case like that at job some week ago.